# Freeing memory allocated from placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, placement-new

Consider the following code,

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

class sample
{
      private:
              int i;
      public:
             sample(int ii=0) : i(ii){                         
                   cout<<"Constructing Object"<<endl; 
                   }

             ~sample() { cout<<"Destructing Object"<<endl; }

             void* operator new(size_t nSize, void* loc){
                   cout <<"Inside new"<<endl;
                   cout <<loc<<endl;
                   return loc;
                   }

             void operator delete(void* ptr){
                  cout <<"Inside delete"<<endl;
                  free(ptr);
                  }
};


int main()
{
    int intArr[2];
    sample* samplePtr = new(intArr) sample(5);
    cout <<samplePtr<<endl;

    delete samplePtr;  
//    samplePtr->sample::~sample();
    getch();
}
```

Output:

```
Inside New
0x22ff38
Constructing Object
0x22ff38
Destructing Object
Inside Delete
```

Here, I am dynamically requesting a memory that's already allocated on stack. I read that i need to call the destructor explicitly once i am done. But when i try and call delete for the memory allocated on stack i get a call to destructor. Does that mean that memory on stack is freed after destructor is called?

If i dynamically request for memory that's allocated on heap earlier, in that case i need to call delete, but does delete actually free memory on stack?

Answer (score 14):

The normal new operator does two things:

1. Calls dynamic memory manager to get chunk of memory
2. Calls constructor

The normal delete operator does the reverse

1. Calls destructor
2. Calls dynamic memory manager to free chunk of memory

Placement new only does one step:

1. Calls constructor

So "placement delete" should only do one step:

1. Calls destructor

You should not call normal delete after placement new, as you have done.  (The reason is that doing so would ask the dynamic memory manager to delete a block it did not allocate, resulting in undefined behaviour)

This line is wrong:

```
delete samplePtr;  // WRONG
```

You need to do "placement delete" which is just a raw call the descructor:

```
samplePtr->~sample(); // CORRECT
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I just need to call the destructor. And once the object goes out of scope automatically the corresponding memory on stack will be freed.

Comment: For the sake of precise wording: new-operator only ever allocates memory. Correct name for a line like: `T* p = new T;` is **new-expression**. It is new-expression that invokes **new-operator** first, and then invokes the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing (free memory with `free` that was not allocated by `malloc`) causes undefined behavior - anything could happen. Same with `delete`ing a pointer that was not obtained via `new`. Same with `delete`ing a pointer obtained from `malloc` or the opposite.

Just because it appears to "work" doesn't mean it is correct. You must not `free` stack memory. You are correct that you need to call the destructor directly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is why placement new can be *bad* (in fact you should avoid it where possible, in this case, just stack allocate the *object*), you shouldn't `delete` the memory (because it was never created by `new` in the first place, rather, you need to do `samplePtr->~sample();`